# Login pages in php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, login-script

I want to create a log in page but it will not work. Can anyone see the error. thank you

i have a database where i have 3 rows email - password - custermer_id.

```
<?
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$login = $_POST['login'];
$user_custermers_id = $_GET['id'];

if($login = 'yes')
{
    global $wpdb;

    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM das_custermer_users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_result($get, 0);
    if($result != 1)
    {
        $msg = "WRONG MESSEGE";
    }
    else
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header("location: http://tgdashboard.com");
    }
}
?>
```

my HTML

```
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <div class="header">
        Loginoplysninger
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="user">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="pass">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
```

Comment: What  error are you getting??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain how your code is failing to work. You're not supposed to just dump code and make us guess.

Comment: First of all, you're using the `mysql` functions - don't do that - use something updated instead like PDO. Second of all you're not using the wordpress database handle `$wpdb`. Use that instead. Third of all, you're not escaping your strings when you paste them into your SQL query, this makes your code very vunerable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have have already given a `value` of `Login` to your submit button here

`<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">` And you are checking if Login is `yes`here

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$user_custermers_id = $_GET['id'];



    if($login = 'yes'){
```

So, You are checking if value is `yes` when you have already set value to `Login`

You should do something like

```
   $login = $_POST['login'];
    $user_custermers_id = $_GET['id'];



        if($login = 'Login'){
```

**Also** as the user below, has noted `if($login = 'yes'){` means you are assigning, a value of `yes` to variable `$login`, which means, if you want to check if you have to use `==` operator, instead. like `if($login == 'yes'){`

Comment: `if($login = 'yes')` will **always** be `true`, as he doesn't compare the two, but rather sets `$login` to `yes`. Use `==` or `===` for comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code it may work for you.. Because i have changed this to wordpress.pls check this.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $email = $_POST['user']; //$_POST['email'];
    $password= $_POST['pass']; //$_POST['password'];
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $user_custermers_id = $_GET['id'];

    if($login == 'Login' || isset($login)) 
    {
        global $wpdb;

        /*$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM das_custermer_users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_result($get, 0);*/
        $get = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM das_custermer_users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'", ARRAY_A);
        if ($get != null) 
        {
            // do something with the link 
            $_SESSION['custermer_id'] = $get->das_custermers_id;
            $das_custermer_id = $get->das_custermers_id;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            //echo 'custermer-id'.$get->das_custermers_id.'custermer-idbysession'.$_SESSION['custermer_id'].'email'.$email.'emailby session'.$_SESSION['email'];
            header("location: http://tgdashboard.com?das_custermers_id=".$das_custermer_id);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // no link found
            $msg = "WRONG MESSEGE";
        }
    }
?>
```

try this it will work for you..

```
<?php
session_start();
$email = $_POST['user']; //$_POST['email'];
$password= $_POST['pass']; //$_POST['password'];
$login = $_POST['login'];
$user_custermers_id = $_GET['id'];

if($login == 'Login' || isset($login)) 
{
    global $wpdb;

    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM das_custermer_users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());

    //$result = mysql_result($get, 0);
    $result = mysql_num_rows($get);  // try this..
    if($result == 0)
    {
        $msg = "WRONG MESSEGE";
    }
    else
    {
        //session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header("location: http://tgdashboard.com");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i cant understand why.. :/

Comment: I cant understand why i get the WRONG message... But how Can $result be 1..??

Comment: can u use this line $result = mysql_num_rows($get);

Comment: I have edited my answer pls go through this.**$result = mysql_num_rows($get);**

Comment: Now nothing happens... no "WRONG MESSEGE" or login.. :/

Comment: just echo the value echo "count".mysql_num_rows($get); and its redirect to the http://tgdashboard.com this page.. put this session_start() to the top of the each page like this                     <?php
session_start();

Comment: $email = $_POST['user']; //$_POST['email'];
$password= $_POST['pass']; //$_POST['password'];

Comment: change this also your **form Email id name as user and password name as pass** but in your php code use **$_POST['email'] and $_POST['password']** change this to the particular name **$_POST['user'] and $_POST['pass']**.I have **edited this in my answer** also pls check this..

Comment: whats this **global $wpdb;** ? its having any connection string like     this $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("db_name",$con) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: but hou can i get my custermer-id in my url..??

Comment: by this only $_SESSION['custermer-id'] = $get->custermer-id; in your redirected page just put echo $_SESSION['custermer-id']; its displays custermer-id. i have edited in answer also..

Comment: $_SESSION['custermer_id'] = $get->custermer_id; this is not working

Comment: I have edited the answer just print the response. because once query has been executed successfully means it redirect to second page but now it remains in same page and print some response. i need that(sent that) response after that i will solved your problem.

Comment: i have changed **custermer-id to das_custermers_id** check it now..if its print any custemer_id in this page.

Comment: it only show the session... but i need das_custermers_id in my URL :)

Comment: check it now das_custermers_id was showed in your url... i have edited in my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, several things here, as I've also noted in my comment.

**Firstly,** you're using `mysql_query`, yet obviously using wordpress (`global $wpdb`) (WordPress doesn't use these functions, and they're outdated and deprecated, [**please read this**](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and use the [`$wpdb->get_results()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row) function instead).

**Secondly,** you're not escaping your input, which means I could type in an email being `' OR email = 'admin@site.com'; --` and log in as any user I wanted to. In wordpress, you're looking for `$wpdb->escape()` or look into [prepared statements in wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb_Class#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).

**Thirdly,** please do not use short tags (`<?`) as you can't be sure they're enabled in all PHP configs where you deploy this code. Better stick with `<?php`.

**Fourthly,** as others have mentioned you're "comparing" (see fifthly) `$login` to `yes`, but it is never yes, because the value of your submit button is `Login`.

**Fifthly,** you're not comparing `$login` to `yes`, you're setting `$login` to `yes`. Use `==` instead for comparison.

So the final suggested code should look something like this:

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $user_custermers_id = $_GET['id'];

    if($login == 'Login') //Changed to == and 'Login'
    {
        global $wpdb;

        //Changed to actually use $wpdb instead and get_results and escaping variables
        $get = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM das_custermer_users WHERE email = '" . $wpdb->escape($email) . "' AND password = '" . $wpdb->escape($password) . "'");

        //As $wpdb works different, use this
        if (!empty($get)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            header("location: http://tgdashboard.com");
        } else {
            $msg = "WRONG MESSAGE";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks.. but it does not work ..:/ i cant see what is wrong :(